# Limit shipping to specific State's only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to limit shipping to my customer to specific states only. Actually i want to show specific states on my shipping address state field. I have try this

```
function patricks_only_ship_to_continental_us( $available_methods ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $excluded_states = array( 'AK','HI','GU','PR' );

    if( !in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_state(), $excluded_states ) ) {
        // Empty the $available_methods array
        $available_methods = array();
    }

    return $available_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'patricks_only_ship_to_continental_us', 10 );
```

but this seems to be not working as a expected, Its throws error message while placing the order. I don't want my customer select invalid shipping method.

I have also tried these filter but they change both shipping and billing address state field

```
woocommerce_states
woocommerce_countries_allowed_country_states
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of enable shipping to limited state of india only.
place below code into your function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
    $states['IN'] = array(
        'GA' => __( 'Goa', 'woocommerce' ),
        'JK' => __( 'Jammu and Kashmir', 'woocommerce' ),
        'JH' => __( 'Jharkhand', 'woocommerce' ),
        'GJ' => __( 'Gujarat', 'woocommerce' )
     );
    return $states;
}
```

Modify array list by listing of state where you want to enable shipping.
You can get list of state code from woo commerce default state
plugins\woocommerce\i18n\states

Comment: Tried before but its changed both shipping and billing address state field whereas I just want to change shipping state field.

Comment: Why is it so hard to change what should be very simply. I don't care where people pay from, but where I can deliver an item is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I'll post as an answer, There are a lot of plugins that can do this by adding something like a search bar where you're customer can enter there zip code and check if you are delivering in that place.  It can also restrict them to add anything in a cart if they haven't checked their zip code yet.

Here's the list of plugin's I know so far. Everything's paid though

1. http://gremlin.io/shop/woocommerce-plugins/restrict-check-cod-payment-method-zip-pin-codes-woocommerce
2. http://codecanyon.net/item/zip-code-checker/8740060
3. http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-triggers-add-instant-interactivity-to-wp/3516401?sso%3FWT.ac=search_item&ref=cmoreira&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=deptweb730&ref=cmoreira&clickthrough_id=410306377&redirect_back=true